# Computing a 3D path from one point to another observed at a distance

Tags: 3d, path-connected

I am trying to fly a spacecraft from a point P orbiting point 3D point X, where the viewer is looking directly at X, to a point Q orbiting another 3D point Y.  During the flight I want the view to smoothly follow the path between X and Y so that it appears to the viewer that the spacecraft is simply turning to Y and flying to it.

Whilst that is happening, the spacecraft should move from it's current position (P) at a fixed orbit distance (D1) from X to a new point (Q), a fixed orbit distance (D2) from Y (and those distances will not be the same).

[image: Figure A]

So over time T, I essentially need to compute two 3D coordinates that represent:

1. The point in space that the viewer is looking at; and
2. The point in space at which the spacecraft has moved to.

For this, we can ignore speed, as the transition is to happen over a fixed amount of time, T.

I've tried to manage this in two stages:

1. By approximating a point (F1) between P and Q at the initial distance between P and X, and for the first part of the flight, fly to that point whilst focusing on a point between F1 and Y
2. then once the spacecraft reaches that distance from P, shift the view focus to Y over time whilst continuing to move the spacecraft to Y.

But this does not work well.  The view seems to track on X until after passing it (so I get what looks like a neat Jupiter flyby which is not what I want) and then the camera violently flips back towards Y.

I'm thinking that my non-math brain is going at this the wrong way.  Here is another figure that shows what I *think* the path of the viewpoint and the path of the spacecraft need to be.

[image: Figure B]

I'm hoping that someone can help me get this right.

Here is a short clip of what I'm seeing right now.

[Bad Flight Path][3]

[3] http://pkclsoft.com/downloads/badflightpath.mov

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! :)

Comment: Thanks.  I've been here before and I thought I'd asked questions too, but maybe it's another "exchange".

Comment: Having slept on it, I have a rough solution where I just LERP the two coordinates along lines between X and Y for the view, an P and Q for the spacecraft.  It works, but it assumes that the spacecraft can thrust in a universal direction as its direction of movement is not synchronised with that of the view.

Comment: that is indeed another way to see it; I haven't done a lot of this kind of math but I just dug into it yesterday (because, interesting!) but i did not know you could think of it that way;  uhm.. so really +1 thanks for coming with that comment